# Change Style of an exported html from Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook

I have written a jupyter notebook and exported it as Test1.html, the generated code is as follow.

The notebook is pretty simple made up of two cells.

[image]

I want to change the css file of this HTML to look like this!

[image]

The css code I followed is available [here](https://medium.com/@formigone/my-first-custom-theme-for-jupyter-notebook-a9c1e69efdfe)

Although I was successful in making changes to my Jupyter Notebook main css file. When I export the file as HTML it goes back to the traditional look. Could I have the same looks in my exported notebook? If so, how?

```
In[1]: # Here we go!
In[2]: # Let us try to get the size of string in bytes
len("Test the following code".encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way around this is to navigate to the jupyter notebook

> 1. Go to File
> 2. Print Preview
> 3. Right-click on the new open tab
> 4. save as HTML

This worked for me but I hope I can see better answers!